# Two layer neural network performs worse than single layer

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm learning TensorFlow, and trying to create a simple two layer neural network.

The tutorial code https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros starts with this simple network, to get 92% accuracy:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
```

I tried replacing it with this very simple network, adding a new layer, **but accuracy now drops to 84%**!!!

```
layer1_len = 10
w1 = weight_var([784, layer1_len])
b1 = bias_var([layer1_len])
o1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, w1) + b1)
w2 = weight_var([layer1_len, 10])
b2 = bias_var([10])
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(o1, w2) + b2)
```

I get that result with several different values for `layer1_len` as well as different numbers of training steps.  (Note that if I omit the `weight_var` and `bias_var` random initialization, and keep everything at zero, accuracy drops to close to 10%, essentially no better than guessing.)

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: You should be aware, that increasing the number of layers may result on a model that's more prone to Overfitting, I recommend you to plot the Error training curves (Epochs vs Train/Validation Loss), if the validation loss starts increasing, then you might be experimenting Overfitting

Comment: Do you think overfitting is plausible with `layer1_len = 10`?

Comment: Well, it could be a possibility, the other possible hypothesis is that the model is underfitting. Once again, checking the error loss may give you some insight

Comment: As @EdgarAndrésMargffoyTuay mentioned, more layers increases the likelihood of overfitting. You can try reducing the number of neurons in the model if you want more layers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong. The problem is that increasing layers does not automatically means a higher accuracy (otherwise machine learning would be kind of solved, because if you need a better accuracy in an image classifier you would just add +1 layer to an inception and claim a victory).

To show you that this is not only your problem - take a look at this high-level paper: [Deep Residual Learning for Image Recognition](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf) where they see that increasing the number of layers decreases the scoring function (which is not important) and their architecture to overcome this problem (which is important). Here is a small part from it:[image]

> The deeper network has higher training error and thus test error.